# How to programmatically install a Kernel Mode Driver on Windows 7

Tags: .net, winapi, driver, wdf

I have a signed driver package containing sys, inf, cat, coinstaller files for Keyboard. I need to install the package like the Windows Device Manager. I tried PnpUtil, it did install the driver and place it in the driver store but did not reflect in Device Manager. I tried InstallHInfSection and nothing happened. Which API installs the driver like Device Manager?

Comment: Is there a corresponding device attached to the system?  Is your driver the preferred choice for the device?

Comment: Its a filter driver for the keyboard. The preferred driver is definitely the windows keyboard driver but I need to find a way to programmatically install this driver like the device manager. Im able to install this driver through the Device Manager

Comment: Have you tried using DiInstallDevice?

Comment: I had a look at examples but haven't tried it. Will give it a try. I need to update my keyboard driver, DiInstall will work? Or have to search the Update version of the same API?

Comment: An update is just an uninstall followed by an install.  I don't think you'll need to do the uninstall manually, DiInstallDevice should do it for you.